# What is Lazybones award and how to get it?

Tags: paradise-island

What is **Lazybones** award and how to get it?

The name of this award doesn't say anything to me, in fact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, checked out wikia.com and got this from under the game Paradise Island.

**Lazybones**

Let 20 buildings be unrepaired at the same time.

The reward is 5€.

You can visit the link here : http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Awards